# Allow third party cookies in Chrome Webdriver configuration

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I know there are already answered questions in the same topic, but i can't figure it out from those, how do you enable third party cookies with ChromeOptions in newer versions of Selenium in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below to add cookie to the current browser:

```
 driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
```

Comment: It adds cookies to the website's application, not to the third party sites and i have 16 cookies, that's why i'm looking for a chrome option that enables all of them.